# amsmath is now latex-amsmath: what does this mean for me?

Tags: packages, amsmath

I saw in the latest updates to CTAN that the `amsmath` package is now called `latex-amsmath`. What effects is this change going to make for me? Am I going to have to `\usepackage{latex-amsmath}` in the future, when my TeX distribution updates?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No difference at all, you may not have noticed but earlier in the year the latex graphics package catalogue entry similarly changed to `latex-graphics`.

This is simply a matter of organising the catalogue so that there can be separate entries for `latex-amsmath` which covers the whole bundle `amsmath`, `amstext`, `amscd` etc, and for `amsmath` which just refers to the `amsmath.sty` package itself. Similarly `latex-graphics` in the CTAN catalogue includes `graphicx` and `color` but `graphics` in the catalogue is just `graphics.sty`.

It has no affect on the installed files at all.

Separately from this catalogue entry change, `amsmath` has been updated so that it does not generate errors every time it is used once `luatex` is updated to 0.89 (as planned for texlive 2016).

Comment: Got it. I went to CTAN, and I see now that there are two entries now in the catalog, one for each `amsmath` and `latex-amsmath`. Do you know if they will keep both entries? I see that the documentation for the [`latex-amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex-amsmath) entry is already (rather significantly) different from the documentation for the [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) entry.

Comment: @AnthonyMottaz I'm sure they'll do whatever I ask (I uploaded the update:-)

Comment: @AnthonyMottaz There have been several edits done to the catalogue entries it may take a day or two to reach all mirrors so hopefully it'll be in a stable state soon enough.